# Filter results by score

Tags: open-search-server

I'm using OpenSearchServer and trying to guess how to filter a search result by their scores.

Let's say that I have a search with some set of results. All results are ordered by score is descending order. What I need to know is how I can set up the search for fetching only documents whose scores are greater than 0,3.

is it possible? I ca not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Oh boy you performed very bad. Here is the [query](http://www.opensearchserver.com/documentation/api_v2/search_parameters/README.md) and [this](http://www.opensearchserver.com/documentation/faq/querying/how_to_use_filters_on_query.md) is the filter documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on the virtual field `_score`.